# How to loop through facter blockdevices to mount aws ephemeral disks

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet

I want to mount aws ephemeral devices

```
/dev/xvde on /mnt/ephemeral0
/dev/xvdf on /mnt/ephemeral1
/dev/xvdg on /mnt/ephemeral2
/dev/xvdh on /mnt/ephemeral3
```

for example. If I choose a smaller machine size, I have fewer ephemeral devices so it has to be a dynamic discovery of devices.

I have something in mind like this using facter, but I'm struggling with puppet syntax badly.

As requested, here the output from facter on a machine with 2 ephemeral devices:

```
./facter |grep xv
blockdevice_xvda_size => 8589934592
blockdevice_xvdf_size => 16380329984
blockdevice_xvdg_size => 16380329984
blockdevices => xvda,xvdf,xvdg
```

From this I want to generate /etc/fstab mounts, so xvde and xvdf are available on /mnt/ephemeral0 and /mnt/ephemeral1 respectively.

```
class mystuff::ephemeral () {

    mount { $blockdevices:

      pseudecode:
         loop through blockdevice that don't match xvda, reset ephemeral counter to 0
          if blockdevice match regex xvd[e-h] create an entry in fstab for /dev/xvd[which ever was matched] /mnt/ephemeral$counter
          increase counter by 1
      mount -a
    }
}
```

Update: below the dirty hack I've employed to get myself out of a rut:

```
    mount { 'unmount_mnt':
        name     => '/mnt',
        ensure   => absent,
    }

    exec { 'fstab':
        command  => 'X=0; for i in $(/bin/cat /proc/partitions | /bin/awk \'{print $4}\' |/bin/grep xvd[f-i]);do /bin/mkdir /mnt/ephemeral$X; /bin/echo /dev/$i /mnt/ephemeral$X ext3 defaults,nofail,noexec  0 2 ; X=$((X+1))  ; done >> /etc/fstab && mount -a',
        unless   => '/bin/grep ephemeral /etc/fstab >/dev/null 2>&1',
        provider => shell,
        notify   => Service['auditd'],
        path     => ["/bin"],
        require  => Mount['unmount_mnt'],
    }
```

I need advise on how to use facter and how I can construct the loop in an elegant way without using puppet exec.

Comment: the ephemera disks get same name every time or not?

Comment: How to `dynamic discovery` these ephemera disks?

Comment: AWS instance sizes influence the number of ephemeral devices. The device names are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

After review your request with updated information, I recommend you work it out by this way. The instance should be created from an AMI image with facter installed already.

When launch (create) a new instance, insert below `user data` (in advance option), so it will mount emphemeral disks automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

emphemeral=$(facter|awk -F "_" '/xvd[f-i]/&&/_size/{print $2}' )
let x=0

for i in ${emphemeral}
do
   mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /dev/${i}
   mkdir -p /mnt/ephemeral${x}
   mount /dev/${i} /mnt/ephemeral${x}
   echo "/dev/${i} /mnt/ephemeral${x} auto defaults,nofail,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig  0 2" >> /etc/fstab
   (( x++ ))
done
```

### [image]

Here is the old answer, it is not suitable for your question, but it is another workaround for nominated ephemeral disk.

```
define mystuff::ephemeral(
        $device,
        $name,
      ) {
           mount { "${name}":
             device  => $device,
             fstype  => "ext4",
             ensure  => "mounted",
             options => "defaults",
             atboot  => "true",
        }

}
```

You can apply a manifest like this:

```
mystuff::ephemeral {'ephemeral0':
      device  => '/dev/xvde',
      name    => '/mnt/ephemeral0,  
}
```

Comment: The idea was to use information from facter. The equivalent in shell would be cat /proc/partitions and find xvd[f-h] and create some lines in fstab.

Comment: could you please run the command `cat /proc/partitions` and put the output in your original question?

Comment: I've included output from facter in the question.

Comment: Can I understand it by this way, every time, when the ec2 instance starts up, you will have one partition `xvda` to mount as `/`, and the rest partitions, such as `xvdf` or `xvdf` or the name will be ephemeral disks?

Comment: xvd[f-i] will always be ephemeral, but there could be 0, 1, 2 or 4 such devices.

Comment: Ok, got it, always start fro `xvdf`, let me think. Do you accept to set `exec` module to do that? for example, I create a shell script, and exec with puppet?

Comment: No. I considered userdata already. It's not clean and not practical for us. Your example assumes facter is installed when the instance boots first time. This may not be the case. My shell script works using basic Linux commands, and could easily be implemented in userdata but I've chosen not to, as I feel this is a puppet task, and it's tightly linked to other things going on inside the vm.

Comment: If you can get similar ephemeral disk information from `/proc/partitions`, then you needn't facter to be installed. Here I have a question for you, if you want to do every thing from puppet, then how you get puppet work from beginning. You still need a special AMI with Puppet pre-installed, or you need install puppet via `user data`. `user data` is useful in this case, and also popular in Cloudformation template, auto scaling group, ec2 instance launch, why not think about it with easy way and stick on that dead end?